# What is the difference between DataBinding and Rebinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datasource

I'm a little new to programming and I just began reading about DataBinding methods. I came across the Rebinding method as well and at first glance they seem to do the very same things. There doesn't seem to be an actual answer anywhere.

Is there a difference to using `DataBind()` again whenever you make changes to your DataSource or using `Rebind()` every time?

Answer (score 2):

I could say databind logic happens at the time of binding like initial load. And another one rebinding is like after doing some operation like row edited, row deleted, etc. Something like after postback the data holded by the control (let's say a gridview) will be lost. So to make sure that data is in same view we use rebind. Hope i answered your question. i guess rebinding() is not there in built. its a nomenclature.